# Use of "exponent" and "base" field in "Create Tiled Clones" in inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I am learning Inkscape and in the “Tiled Clones” topic, I learned a lot of things and their uses, but I am unable to understand the use of “exponent” and the “base” field in several tabs of “Create Tiled Clones” dialog.

Kindly guide me about the meaning, in-depth working and applications of these two fields.

I have search on both google and YouTube, but found completely no use of any of these fields.

[image]

Comment: Welcome on GD.SE, Ammar. Have you tried to follow tutorials like [this](https://www.chrishilbig.com/inkscape-experiments-scale-create-tiled-clones-window/)? Can you tell us something more about your efforts?

Comment: Hi! I am following this tutorial http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### For math-lovers (exact formulas only):

Let

- **size<sub>0</sub>** be the appropriate size (horizontal or vertical) of the original (cloned) object,
- **size<sub>0</sub>**, **size<sub>1</sub>**, **size<sub>2</sub>**, **...** the sizes of its clones
  (the first – **0<sup>th⁣</sup>** – clone, is always an exact clone of the original object positioned just over it, so it has *the same  size* as the original object), and
- **scale**, **base** and **exponent** have the same values as they are entered in the **Scale X** (or **Scale Y**), **Base** and **Eponent** field, respectively..

Then to calculate **size<sub>n</sub>**, we first calculate an intermediate value
**exponent<sub>n</sub>**, then a coefficient (multiplicator) **coef<sub>n</sub>**, and finally we multiply the size of the original element by it:

[image]

Now you may derive all important properties from these formulas.

(For math-haters I will prepare another answer with illustration of these properties sometimes later.)

---

*Note:*

To verify the correctness of the above formula, you may use this Python code:

```
N = 5           # How many calculated sizes will be printed
DECIMALS = 3    # How many digits after decimal point

base  = 1.3
scale = 120
expo  = 1.1

exponents = [(1 + scale/100 * n) ** expo for n in range(N)]

if base == 0:
    coeffs = exponents
else:
    coeffs = [base ** (exponent - 1) for exponent in exponents]

rounded_coeffs = [round(coeff, DECIMALS) for coeff in coeffs]
    
print(rounded_coeffs)
```

The output:

> ```
> [1.0, 1.436, 2.108, 3.138, 4.72]
> ```

agrees with sizes of Tiled Clones in Inkscape:

[image]

Comment: Nice explaination... Thanks a lot. Does the cumulative checkbox also serve the same purpose? Multiply each successive copy with a value being increased in some way?

Comment: But still I am unsure what those individual formulaes pose effect on the size and shape of the clones.

Comment: @AmmarMujtabaTariq: **1.** There are no individual formulas, it is the sequence of the 3 relatively simply steps to obtain the result. (I decided to divide the one complex formula to such steps to not scare you. **2.** They are *clones*, so they don't change their shape in any way (except their expanding / contracting along one or both axes).

Comment: @AmmarMujtabaTariq: *Nice explanation... Thanks a lot.* — You're welcome. Please consider accepting and / or upvoting my answer. — *Does the cumulative checkbox also serve the same purpose?* - Please create a new question for it, so all people in this community may find / answer it; then you may obtain the best answer for you, probably a better one than from only 1 person (me).

Answer (score 1):

###### An introductory, very general answer:

If you don't use a rotation (the `Rotation` tab):

- *you may forget about the “Base” fields and keep their default values (zeroes).*

  You may reach practically the same effect with changing the “Exponent” field(s) only instead of adjusting both “Base” and “Exponent”.

The Base and Exponent fields are designated mainly for **cooperation with rotation**, and have impact simultaneously

- on **sizes of clones**,
- on the **shape of the rotational path** for placing clones.

Beside others, this path may be

- a circle (`Exponent = 0`),
- an [Archimedes spiral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ArchimedesSpiral.html) (`Base = 0`), or
- a [Logarithmic spiral](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogarithmicSpiral.html) (`Exponent = 1`).

The expression **"cooperation with rotation"** means that change of sizes ("growth") depends on the shape of the (rotational) path. For example, for a *circular path* there is no growth (`Scale X` and `Scale X` are *totally ignored – all clones will have the same sizes as the original object):*

[image]

---

An example of the cloning along a logarithmic spiral (together with the used values):

In the Scale tab:

[image]

---

In the Rotation tab:

[image]